# Is the image clarity improved if it is shrinked to a div smaller than its real pixel

Tags: html, css, image, pixel

Below code is the area to load an image. There are two images with different pixels here. The are scanned from the scanner with exactly the same thing, but with different dpi. So the final two images have different pixels. Image A is `850px * 850px`, and Image B is `1700px * 1700 px`.

If A is loaded into this area, its width will be shrinked into 510px, since the max-width here is set in CSS. If B is loaded into this area, its width will also be `510px`.

I know that if an image with `100px * 100px`, and put it into this `510px * 510 px` area, it will be extended and its clarity will be reduced.

But the two bigger images here, they are also shrinked from `850px` and `1700px` into the same `510px`, will their clarity are the same? Or the `1700px` is more clear?

```
<div class="image-container" style="height: 510px; max-width: 510px;">
     <img src="xxxx/xxxx/xxxx" id="target" style="max-width: 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is that the bigger image will be sharper, but this will depend on the image itself, the sampling algorithm the scanner uses, and the browser-specific resizing algorithm. Why not simply check what happens in your specific case?

Comment: @MichaelHaddad Hi, I already checked. I didn't see much difference for the two images. Maybe we can say it this way. If a div is `510px`, so it will use 510 pixel points in the computer screen to display it. But if the image is `1700px*1700px`, how the computer uses pixel points in screen to display it?